# Strange behavior with ^ character

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to make create a simple RegEx to test whether a string is a valid variable name (starts with a letter or _, followed by more of these or digits).

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
bool match = Regex.IsMatch(@"abc",@"^[a-zA-z_][a-zA-z_0-9]*$"); // TRUE as expected
bool match = Regex.IsMatch(@"=abc",@"^[a-zA-z_][a-zA-z_0-9]*$"); // FALSE as expected
bool match = Regex.IsMatch(@"0abc",@"^[a-zA-z_][a-zA-z_0-9]*$"); // FALSE as expected
```

Seems to work fine. But:

```
bool match = Regex.IsMatch(@"^abc",@"^[a-zA-z_][a-zA-z_0-9]*$"); // TRUE. WHY?!
```

How is it possible that =abc does not match but ^abc does? It almost seems like the caret somehow breaks the RegEx engine. But that can't be the case. What's wrong with my RegEx?

Comment: What a bizarre 2 downvotes - your question is perfectly clear.

Comment: To actually answer your question: you have a typo, and the regex should read: `@"^[a-zA-z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*$"`

Comment: It is perfectly clear that the typo is in `A-z`. Use `A-Z` or the `A-z` range will match more than you need.

Comment: Oh, I found a much better duplicate source - [I answered the same question some months ago](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29771926/3832970).